# Question regarding the finite intersection property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose I have a sequence $\{C _j \} $ of closed and bounded intervals such that $ \cap _{j=1 } ^{\infty } C _j= \emptyset$. Does it follow that for some $n $, we must have $\cap _{j } ^n E _j = \emptyset$

I believe this is the only possibility since otherwise the assumption would violate the finite intersection property.

Comment: Does $\cap_j^nE_j$ mean $\cap_{j=1}^nE_j$? What is $E_j$, and how is it related to $C_j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct in a space where closed and bounded intervals are compact. If every finite intersection were nonempty, this would also be true when intersect all the other intervals with a single interval. In that case compactness gives us the result.

Comment: closed+bounded=compact is true in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: It's true more generally though, and they didn't specify the space.

Answer (score 0):

It  can be concluded iff the space is compact .If the space is compact then for every sequence of closed intervals possessing finite intersection property ,the intersection of the entire collection is non empty

Comment: The OP was asking essentially whether a collection of compact intervals with the finite intersection property had nonempty intersection. This is true regardless of whether the larger space is compact.